# Issue with Websocket upgrade request in Jetty-9.2.2

Tags: websocket, jetty, cometd, jetty-9

Using : Jettyv9.2.2 and CometD-3.0.1

As discussed [Ordering of filters, servlets in Jetty-9.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741365/ordering-of-filters-servlets-in-jetty-9-2-2) Jetty has servlet filter that is always added as first filter by a ServletContainerInitializer. So the upgrade request will hit the WS filter that's in the front of the chain first.

In my use case: I have added my local filters in web.xml. And as mentioned above, the request should not hit my filter. But when I checked the logs, I can clearly see that upgrade request is hitting my filters. If upgrade has happend then why my local filters are getting invoked ?

Some observation: 
Everytime request hit my filter in a separate thread while other CometD calls and jetty filters are getting invoked in another thread.

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade, during JSR-356 should always be first on Jetty.

This is likely a bug, and is marked at https://bugs.eclipse.org/444517

Subscribe to that bug for updates.