# How does ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator work

Tags: servlets, websocket, jetty

It is coming from 
[Ordering of filters, servlets in Jetty-9.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741365/ordering-of-filters-servlets-in-jetty-9-2-2/25747444#25747444)

As mentioned 
"split out the security logic into a standalone class that your Servlet Filters and your custom javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator can use."

I am not sure how to implement this ? Can someone please explain this ?

Answer (score 3):

An HTTP upgrade (aka websocket) request arrives, what happens?

1. The container sees that it has the various headers indicating that it is an Upgrade request for websocket.

   - Is request method `GET`?
   - Is `Upgrade` header value `WebSocket`?
   - Is `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header value present and valid?
   - Is `Sec-WebSocket-Version` header value present and valid?
2. The container attempts to find if something is mapped to that incoming request (using a combination of servlet path mapping rules and javax.websocket uri template path mapping rules).
3. Once a registered endpoint is discovered from the above rules, it has to be initialized and configured before it is considered open.
4. The [`ServerEndpointConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.html) for that endpoint is used (all endpoints have this class registered with them, some are default values, some are calculated from annotations, and some are provided via the [`ServerContainer.addEndpoint(ServerEndpointConfig)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html#addEndpoint(javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig)) method.
5. The following order is used to initialize a websocket endpoint

   1. Container establishes a [`HandshakeRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/HandshakeRequest.html) and [`HandshakeResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/HandshakeResponse.html) object representing the incoming raw upgrade request
   2. Container obtains a [`Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html) from [`ServerEndpointConfig.getConfigurator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.html#getConfigurator())
   3. Container calls [`Configurator.modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#modifyHandshake(javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig,%20javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest,%20javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse))
   4. Container calls [`Configurator.checkOrigin(String origin)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#checkOrigin(java.lang.String)) - if this fails, then an immediate error 403 Forbidden is returned
   5. Container calls [`Configurator.getNegotiatedSubprotocol(List<String> supported, List<String> requested)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getNegotiatedSubprotocol(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)) - if a subprotocol is provided, it is used for the WebSocket upgrade response header `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol`
   6. Container calls [`Configurator.getNegotiatedExtensions(List<Extension> installed, List<Extension> requested)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getNegotiatedExtensions(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)) - values returned are used in the WebSocket upgrade response header `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions`
   7. Container calls [`Configurator.getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getEndpointInstance(java.lang.Class)) with endpoint class parameter that the `ServerEndpointConfig` was created with.
   8. At this point the `Endpoint` + `Session` are created and websocket is opened.

If at any point you do not wish to upgrade this request, just throw an exception from the `getEndpointInstance` class.  I'd recommend a [`java.lang.InstantiationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html).
This will cause Jetty to not perform the upgrade and send the request down the servlet processing chain.

Do note, however, your options on how your http response looks like from the Configurator is extremely limited (and rather undefined per the JSR-356/javax.websocket spec).

Comment: `...your options on how your http response... is extremely limited` Does this mean that it's not possible to return specific HTTP response codes using this method?

Comment: @bcoughlan Not with the current JSR356 spec, you'll have to wait for a future update of that spec. (perhaps version 2.0?)